# Single threaded nodejs run "parallelly"?

Tags: node.js

Code snippet below,

```
rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin
})

rl.on('line', (s) => {
    console.log(s)
    rl.close()
})

for (i = 0; i < 2e9; i++) {}
console.log(i)
```

Run it, quickly type a few chars e.g. `abcd` then hit `Enter` before `for` loop ends. Since `for` loop occupies the main thread, the output that I had expected would be:

```
2000000000
abcd
abcd
```

Why did the console show something below instead?

```
abcd
2000000000
abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is nodejs is not single threaded. At least internally it is not. Yes it is single threaded for you but not in itself. So when you wrote the second part of your code which was

```
rl.on('line', (s) => {
    console.log(s)
    rl.close()
})
```

It doesn't run this on the main thread. It has a set of worker threads which it doesn't give you access but maintains internally. So it has separate threads which actually do the IO for you. Hence the output. This guy explains it quite perfectly - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

For further reading [Javascript eventloop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: Any proof of this? So far as I know console.log runs in the main thread. The only multithreaded IO in node is disk IO. Network, tty and pipes don't run on separate threads